# Retrieving POST data from Web2py to local HTML file

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-domain, web2py

I've been having some heavy jquery cross-domain issues, so I've been trying to get around that through web2py.

I'm sending POST data from a local HTML file to my web2py server.  Web2py is then making a python POST to a second server (which solves the cross-domain issue) and gets the expected response.  How should I get that response back to my local html file?

I've thought about storing those results in a database and then retrieving them with a url redirect-- but I'm not sure that I'd be able to guess what URL I would need.  Perhaps just grab the last entry from the database.

Or is there a better method?

I realize there are probably much better methods to do this directly from the original local html file and circumvent web2py completely, but I'm much more comfortable in python than js.

So I'm trying to get from:

[local html file]->[POST to web2py]->[POST to other separate server]->[RESPONSE back to local html file]

I just can't get that last leg figured out.

My controller that posts to the 2nd server (this works):

```
def index():
    response.headers['content-type'] = 'text/xml'
    xml = request.body.read()  
    query_args = { 'data': xml }
    encoded_args = urllib.urlencode(query_args)
    url = 'myserver.com'
    content = urllib2.urlopen(url, encoded_args).read()
    return response.render(dict(content=XML(content)))
```

my local html file post looks like (this POSTS correctly):

```
<script language="javascript">
function check()
 {

jQuery('.myclass').each(function(){ 
       var txt = $(this).serialize();   
            $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'myserver',
data:  'mydata',
statusCode: {
    302: function() {
        alert("302"); // this is never called
    },
    200: function() {
        alert("200");
    },
},
success: function (data, textstatus) {
    console.log(data);

},
error: function (data) {
},

});

});
 }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to put code in the "success" handler that writes web2py's response to the local html document.

Something like:

```
success: function (data, textstatus) {
   $('#some-element').html(data);
},
```

When the post request happens, you could alternatively have the success handler redirect to a new page, and somehow store the XML data in a session variable and see it on the new page, but I think just doing this in javascript will dramatically simplify things.

EDIT: I'm not sure of the nature of your data, so if it really is XML (and not (X)HTML of some sort) then you'll need to process the data in the success callback instead of writing it to a DOM element.

You'll need an empty element, perhaps a div: `<div id='some-element'></div>` to contain the response.

Does this sound like what you need? Let me know if I've misinterpreted.